# CakePHP alphaNumeric allows non-english symbols

Tags: php, cakephp

What should I do if I want to allow only English alphabet to be validated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own rule?

```
var $validate = array(    
   'login' => array(        
      'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9]+$/i',          
      'message' => 'Only letters and integers'    
));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.wiseguysonly.com/2009/11/27/a-workaround-for-the-cakephp-alphanumeric-issue/. The person in that article was having a different but related problem, and their solution is the same as the one you need.

The basic idea is to just use a custom regex. Change this:

```
'rule' => 'alphaNumeric'
```

To this:

```
'rule' => array('custom', '/^[a-z0-9]*$/i')
```

This should also work:

```
'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9]*$/i'
```

The official docs on custom regex validations are at http://book.cakephp.org/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules#Custom-Regular-Expression-Validation-1180.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [regex as the rule](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules#Custom-Regular-Expression-Validation-1180) instead.